# Xampp Apache Feed Duplication/Modification

Tags: php, xampp

First of all, I apologize in advance if my English is bad, I use translation. I will try to explain my problem in the simplest way.

I am working as follows to develop a project:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\[ProjectFolder]
```

Finally I have a directory tree like this:

```
- HTDoCS
--- Project 1
--- Project 2
--- Project 3
```

And to view in browser, as you know, I work like this:

```
http://localhost/projectName
```

This usage gives me trouble when I have too many projects and I have problems when I need to work with .htaccess files. Also, getting the projects published is getting very difficult...

I want to do it like this:

```
http://localhost:8080 -> htdocs/project1
http://localhost:8081 -> htdocs/project2
http://localhost:8082 -> htdocs/project3
```

so I want to make the root folder where each port is hosted another folder under htdocs.

I know how to change port or root folder by making virtualhost, but I have no idea how to make a different root folder for each port I set.

Can you help me please? Thanks to everyone who has already commented...

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. Rather than switching to different ports, you should set up _VirtualHosts_ for each of your projects, plus a local domain name - so that you can access them via something like `http://project1.local`, `http://project2.local`, etc.

Comment: yes i can work if i can get access that way too. Is this how to use this method? http://project1.local -> htdocs/project1 https://project2.local -> htdocs/project2    so my point here is that the url I'm accessing recognizes different folders under htdocs as root folder.

Comment: As I said, the keyword for that is VirtualHosts.